# WPF expandable multi line text box

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a WPF desktop application and have a need for a text box to expand to show additional text.  In this case the text box has a list of error messages but I only want to display a few lines rather than the complete error message.  The user would double click in the text box and it would expand to show the rest of the message.

Comment: You would probably be better off with a ListBox instead. On the click event of an Item, you can toggle the length of the error message for that item.

Comment: Or use an Expander control

Comment: you should write a style for textbox with wordwrap on & some maxheight so that the height doesn't overflow.